# What is the exact command for launching Chrome with remote debugging in Terminal?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging

I've looked up and tried a couple ways of launching Chrome with remote debugging through the terminal, and neither have worked. I get the error "no such directory" or command not found.  I've tried:

```
 chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

and

```
/Applications/Google\Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Are either of these correct? And if not, what is the right command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple change is needed, add the bash shebang to the Chrome Debugger script.

```
#!/bin/bash
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222&
```